# Access 2003 SQL Switch breaks data types?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm running Access 2003.  I'm using Switch to select date fields based on a boolean criterion:

```
Switch(<criterion>, Date1, 1, Date2)
```

i.e., if "criterion" is true, then return Date1, otherwise return Date2.

Date1 and Date2 are Date/Time type columns in a table.

The problem is, Switch returns them as Text -- not Date/Time!

Is there a way to force them into Date-ness?  I tried

```
Switch(<criterion>, #Date1#, 1, #Date2#)
```

And

```
Switch(<criterion>, Val(Date1), 1, Val(Date2))
```

Both of which fail with one error message or another.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Immediate If [IIf()] function is a better match for what you're trying to do:

```
IIf(<criterion>, Date1, Date2)
```

But the Switch() function shouldn't break data types, and is not incompatible with date/time data types.  Consider this function:

```
Public Function trySwitch(ByVal pWhichDay As String) As Variant
    Dim varOut As Variant
    varOut = Switch(pWhichDay = "yesterday", Date - 1, _
        pWhichDay = "today", Date, _
        pWhichDay = "tomorrow", Date + 1)
    trySwitch = varOut
End Function
```

**trySwitch("today")** returns **10/6/2009** and **TypeName(trySwitch("today"))** returns **Date**

Comment: David's and onedaywhen's intriguing explanations notwithstanding, the IIf worked (and I really should have been using it in the first place).  See my comment on onedaywhen's answer for more details of the difference, but for now, I'll just use IIf.

Answer (score 1):

There's something strange with your example.

Switch accepts expression pairs, and if the first evaluates as True, its paired value is returned, otherwise, it passes on to the second, and evaluates that argument.

You seem to be treating 1 as True, which it is because it's not Fales, but you'd be better off with:

```
  Switch(<criterion>, Date1, True, Date2)
```

But that's just a replication of the functionality of the Immediate If function, IIf(), and IIf() takes fewer arguments.

But it has the same problem, in that it returns a variant. But you should be able to coerce that to a data type that can be formatted as a Date.

But whether or not that variant will be implicitly coerced or you'll need to do it explicitly, depends on where you're using it. In a query result, you can sort the output from IIf([criterion], Date1, Date2) as a date, because the column gets coerced to date type.

If you have to do the coercion explicitly, CDate() is the function to use -- you'd wrap the outside function that produces Variant output with the CDate() function in order to be certain that the variant output is explicitly coerced to date type:

```
  CDate(IIf(<criterion>, Date1, Date2))
```

But I might very well be missing something important here, as I appear to be off on a completely different track...

Comment: Interesting: when I wrap Date2 in a CDate() inside the Switch, Access treats the resultset column as a non-date type (see my comment to onedaywhen). But when I wrap the whole Switch statement in CDate, it treats the column as a Date type (by same sorting/cell-justification criteria). i.e. "Switch(<criterion>, Date1, True, CDate(Date2))" is not type-equivalent to "CDate(Switch(<criterion>, Date1, True, Date2))".  [Note: the IIf is still better here, since it will return Null when Date1 is Null, whereas Switch sees a Null Date1 and returns an #Error#, dirtying the resultset]

Comment: I wasn't suggesting coercing the arguments being passed, because those obviously have the correct data type at that point. What you have to coerce to the right data type is the Variant output of Switch() or IIf(), as you found out. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some code and data to reproduce the problem, please? As this is `SWITCH()` in SQL code then I think SQL DDL (`CREATE TABLE` etc) and DML (`INSERT INTO` to add data) would be most appropriate :)

[Picky point: Access Database SQL does not have a 'boolean' data type. It has a `YESNO` data type which can be the `NULL` value; three-value logic is not Boolean.]

Here's some SQL DML ([ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) syntax) to demonstrate how it works as expected for me:

```
SELECT TYPENAME
       (
          SWITCH
          (
             NULL, #2009-01-01 00:00:00#, 
             FALSE, #2009-06-15 12:00:00#, 
             TRUE, #2009-12-31 23:59:59#
          )
       );
```

Change any of the 'criterion' values and the value is always returned as 'Date' i.e. of type `DATETIME`.

---

UPDATE:

> That `TYPENAME` function is a great
>   tool... Access seems to interpret the
>   entire "column" of the resultset
>   differently

Indeed. Because a column can only be one data type the results of `TYPENAME()` at the row can be misleading. Row values of mixed types must be 'promoted' to a higher data type. As is usual with the Access Database Engine, the process is entirely opaque and the documentation on the subject completely absent, so you just have to suck it and see e.g.

```
SELECT #2009-01-01 00:00:00# AS row_value, 
       TYPENAME(#2009-01-01 00:00:00#) AS row_type
  FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT 0.5, 
       TYPENAME(0.5) AS row_type
  FROM Customers
```

returns 'Date' and 'Decimal' respectively but what will the column be? Apparently, the answer is:

```
SELECT DT1.row_value, TYPENAME(DT1.row_value) AS column_type
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT #2009-01-01 00:00:00# AS row_value 
          FROM Customers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT 0.5
          FROM Customers
       ) AS DT1;
```

'String'?!

...which of course isn't even a Access Database Engine SQL data type. So `TYPENAME()`, annoyingly, uses the name of the 'best fit' VBA type. For example:

```
SELECT TYPENAME(CBOOL(0));
```

returns 'Boolean' even though, as discussed above, there is no Boolean data type in Access Database Engine SQL. And

```
SELECT TYPENAME(my_binary_col)
```

returns 'String'. Note the same VBA mapping limitation applies to the `CAST` functions (yet another annoyance) e.g. there is no 'cast to `BINARY`' function and the `CDEC()` function remains broken since Jet 4.0 :(

Comment: That TYPENAME function is a great tool -- +1 for that and the helpful troubleshooting tips.  It tells me my values are 'Date' and 'Null' (for the Null entries, obviously), and the type results per row are the same in the IIf expression and the Switch expression.  But Access seems to interpret the entire "column" of the resultset differently: Date (temporally-sortable, right-justified) for IIf, and something else (lexical sort only, left-justified) for Switch.

Comment: This is because IIf() coerces the return value to a Variant of subtype Date() when both the True and False parts are of type Date. Switch() does not do that -- it just returns a variant (probably of subtype String), and has to be explicitly coerced with CDate().

Comment: @David W. Fenton: remember we are discussing the expressions used in Access Database SQL, which doesn't have Variant or String data types, despite what TYPENAME() might tell you.